# Как сделать ввод в таблицу без id?

Tags: sql

В таблице включен автоинкремент. Нужно в таблицу вставить данные, но я не знаю количество полей для вставки. Я сделал времененную таблицу со всеми нужными полями. Как сделать вставку при этом не пытаясь вставить id который на автоинкременте? Соответственно вариант
Insert into table1
Select *
from #table2

НЕ ПОДХОДИТ.

Comment: если, имея на руках все данные, не знаете какие поля вставлять, то может стоит заняться чем-нибудь другим?

Comment: начните решение вашей проблемы с того, чтобы разобраться, что за поля у вас в момент времени для вставки.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что поле Id объявлено как `int not null identity primary key`
Дальше, можно добавлять значение в таблицу, указав явно какие поля буду добавлять
`insert into Goods(Name, Price)` - будет добавлен товар `(1, 'Морковь', 100)`
или без указания явных полей `insert into Goods values ('Морковь', 100)`.
В таблицу будет занесена та же строка.

Comment: primary key - не обязательно, я взял из своего запроса, т.к. я работаю дальше с идентификатором продукта в других таблицах через объединение.

Comment: Я не могу указать явно какие поля добавлю, ибо не знаю сколько у меня будет полей, в этом и проблема.

Comment: Я сделал временную табличку в которую вбил нужные поля, может как то можно посчитать эти поля и ввести уже, хз...

Comment: Боюсь, не зная какие поля надо добавлять - вряд ли выполнится insert-запрос.

Comment: Считать кол-во строк в таблице - агрегатная функция Count.

Comment: Попробуйте так: http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select20.php

Comment: Интересная идея, только теперь вопрос как строку полученных столбцов заставить работать в селекте?

Comment: @msi - спасибо за ссылку, очень полезно!